# SQL Update Query won't work in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

So I've been trying to figure out what the problem is with my UPDATE SQL query and searched through the questions on here only to find out the issue is with the actual text that's being updated in the database table. My PHP app is a simple one just for adding simple website links with a description to a table (links) as below:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
   <p><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo($desc); ?>" /></p>
   <p><input type="text" name="link" value="<?php echo($link); ?>" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Save Changes" /></p>
</form>
```

Obviously this code is from the edit.php page but when I try to execute the UPDATE statement in update.php it throws out an error stating that there is an issue with the syntax. This only seems to occur when there is a ' in the text for example:

Description: "Mum's Tutition Site"

If I take out the ' in "Mum's" making it "Mums" then it updates fine! Can anyone offer an explanation as to why it does this and possible remedy/code to fix the issue?

Thanks for help in advance!

Dave.

Comment: Use mysql real escape string in case you use mysql library.

Comment: Post your code in update.php

Comment: Have you looked at the final generated HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PDO for your data base handling

It is better to first sanitize you data

```
$data = sanitize("Mom's");    
function sanitize($data){
        $data= htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($data)));
        return $data;
    }
```

Secure way

```
$name = "Mom's";
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename', $user, $pass); 
//establish new connection

$statement = $database->prepare("UPDATE TABLE xyz SET name=?");
$statement->execute(array($name));
```

This will more secure itself. You don't need do manual escapes.

Or use

```
$msg =  mysql_real_escape_string($string);
```

before inserting data

Answer (score 0):

Because when it's finally converted into an Update statement it will be like

```
...somecolname = 'Mum's.....'
```

and the single quote looks like the end of the string. Need to be replace with two single quotes. before putting together into statement

Answer (score -1):

It is dangerous to insert a ' in SQL so it throws an error. It is called SQL Injection. Try using the PHP functions like htmlentities() or addslashes() to deal with the ' before insertion.

Comment: SQL Injection isn't simply inserting a `'` in SQL... it can be quite valid to insert a `'` but it must be escaped, whether manually in your code, or via using prepared statements